# Is a point circle rigorously defined?

Tags: geometry

For example, If there is point P and point O. Then does it make sense to say that power of point P with respect to point circle O = OP^2. Also if a point is a circle then how does the theorem '3 points determine a unique circle' apply here?

Comment: May I ask, what do You mean by a power of a point?

Comment: @user1047209 It's from the fact that given a point and a circle and a line through the point that intersects the circle, the product of the distances from the point to the two intersections is constant, no matter which line you choose. This constant is called the power of the point with respect to the circle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point